# What filter or action to replace comments or add new comment system

Tags: comments, filters, hooks

I am looking to make a plugin for my site, which either replaces the current comments in a post or adds an additional comment system.

I am getting the comments from a custom RSS feed from my forum that is linked to posts. I have this working with the following.

```
function swmc_comments_callback( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
global $post;

include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-simplepie.php'); 

//require 'includes/simplepie.inc';  
$feed = new SimplePie();  
$feed->set_feed_url('<feedurl>?swmc=syndicate&article='.$post->ID); 
$feed->force_feed(true);
$feed->set_item_class();  
$feed->enable_cache(false);  
$feed->set_cache_duration(3600);  
$feed->init();  
$feed->handle_content_type(); 

if ($feed->error())
{
    echo $feed->error();
}

$max = $feed->get_item_quantity();

for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++)   {
    $item = $feed->get_item($x);    

    if ($author = $item->get_author())
    {
        $username = $author->get_name();
    }

    //echo "<br/><br/>title: ".$item->get_title();
    $dan_data = $item->get_description();

    //echo "<br/>Posted on ". $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a');
    //echo  "<br/>username: ".$username;
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php $x; ?>">
    <article id="comment-<?php $x; ?>" class="comment">

        <div class="comment-content"><?php echo $dan_data; ?></div>

        <p><?php echo "Comment author: ".$username; ?></p>


    </article>
    </li>
    <?

}
```

}

I can then use the template by using

```
<?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'swmc_comments_callback' ) ); ?>
```

However whilst this will work. I would like this to work across all themes but I am not sure how to call this without adding it into the template as I have here.

Is there a filter or a hook I should use?

Cheers
Dan

Answer (score -1):

The answer is the filter comments_template

```
add_filter("comments_template", "swmc_comments_template");
```